# Java, return method

Tags: java

There is a method called absolute() that takes an integer parameter and returns its
absolute value. The absolute value of a positive integer x is x. The absolute value of a negative integer –x is also x. I.e. the function should convert negative numbers into
positive ones but leave positive numbers unchanged.
My code:

```
int absolute(int x) {
    boolean y=true;
    if(y==false) return x;
    else return x;  
}
```

In the output I get a mistake(negative amount), but in all times it should be positive...

Comment: You set `y` to `true`, then test if it's `false` immediately after. Moreover, your if and else clause both do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

```
int absolute(int x) {
    if(x < 0) return -x;
    else return x;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your not doing anything in that function. Your just returning the value that you send in.
In your case y is always true so it will return x. Even if it wasnt true it would return x. You should rethink your function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<`-Operator to decide wheter a number is smaller than zero (so you have to multiply it by `-1`... Just an idea.

Comment: I think this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Barranka: And what you are thinking is the Measurement-Unit of Stackoverflow? The post contains EVERYTHING required to solve the issue. So its an answer, even if it is not a copy paste solution.